# Example of $Q((x))$ that doesnt match field of fractions of ring $F[[x]]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a commutative ring without zero divisors and $Q$ -its field of fractions. Let $Q(x)$ be also field of fractions of ring $F[x]$. How can field $Q((x))$ not match field of fractions of ring $F[[x]]$? I need to prove that it can be but i cant come up with any simple-enough counter-example of this $Q$ and $F$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname {Frac}(\mathbb Z[[x]])\subsetneq \mathbb Q((x))$ because $\sum\frac {1}{n!}x^n\in \mathbb Q((x))\setminus \operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb Z[[x]])$

Comment: IMO this answer (basically a flat assertion) would be greatly enhanced by a hint. At worst I can see this answer fooling beginners into thinking any "infinite" series is not in $frac(\Bbb Z[x])$.

Comment: @rschwieb: The OP said he couldn't come up with "any simple-enough counter-example of this $Q$ and $F$ " and I gave a very explicit one. If he or anybody else has some specific question I'll be glad to address it but since this might be homework I preferred not to give all the details right now.